# Lost of data in onPostExecute when using Android Async Tasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a simple async task like the following snippet

```
protected class DownloadArticlesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Category, Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> 
{
..
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(Category... categories) 
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        List<Article> articles = Util.getArticlesFromServer(categories);
        result.put("articles", articles);
        Log.d(TAG, "size = " + articles.size()); // Return 1

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) 
    {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = (ArrayList<Article>) result.get("articles");
        Log.d(TAG, "size = " + articles.size()); // Return 0, why?           
    }
```

}

Why the transfer to `onPostExecute` return empty in size, and **it only happen just sometimes, not always.**

Any idea?

Comment: My guess is that you sometimes just do not receive any data when trying to download.

Comment: @Phil, nope, since I can log the size = 1 in the `doInBackground` but get size = 0 in the `onPostExecute`. The logic suppose is okay since most of the time it is consistent.

Comment: Then inside your doInBackground, you should check the size of "result", not articles.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare `List<Articles> articles;` outside of method doInBackground...
and change`List<Article> articles = Util.getArticlesFromServer(categories);` into `articles = Util.getArticlesFromServer(categories);`

it return zero because the data save in List which is not declare as global.